# Equivalent of $u_n=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}(\sin t)^{2n}\text{d}t$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ let $u_n=\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}2}(\sin t)^{2n}\text{d}t$

How can i find (with a proof) an equivalent of this sequence for $n\rightarrow+\infty$ ?

---

We know that $\forall n\geq 2,\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}2}(\sin t)^{n}\text{d}t=\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}2}(\sin t)^{n-2}\text{d}t-\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}2}(\sin t)^{n-2}(\cos t)^2\text{d}t$ . Let's call that $V_n$.

Therefore by IPP $\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}2}(\sin t)^{n-2}(\cos t)^2\text{d}t=\frac{1}{n-1}V_n$ (ie) $\left(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)V_n=V_{n-2}$

... I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Integrating by parts leads to a recurrence.

Comment: have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals#Equivalence

Comment: The Laplace method can be applied fairly directly.

Comment: @AntonioVargas I don't know it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mookid thanks for the link

We have $\frac{V_{n+2}}{V_n}\leq\frac{V_{n+1}}{V_n}\leq 1$ therefore $\frac{n+1}{n+2}\leq \frac{V_{n+1}}{V_n}\leq 1$ by $\left(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)V_n=V_{n-2}$

It's well know that $(n+1)V_nV_{n+1}=V_0V_1=\frac{\pi}2$ therefore by product of equivalents $(n+1)V_nV_{n+1}\sim nV_n^2$

Thus we have $V_n\sim \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2n}}$. As $u_n=v_{2n}$, we get :

$u_n\sim \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4n}}$

Answer (score 1):

Using the properties of Wallis integrals as they are given in the link provided by mookid,$$u_n=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}(\sin t)^{2n}\text{d}t=W_{2n}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2 \Gamma (n+1)}$$ For large values of $n$, an asymptotic development is then $$\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}-\frac{1}{16} \sqrt{\pi }
   \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{3/2}+\frac{1}{256} \sqrt{\pi }
   \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{5/2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{7/2}\right)$$ the first term of which corresponding to what Hippalectryon gave in his answer.